# Split .txt file into separate files taking name from one column and contents from another?

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I apologize if this has already been asked. I've looked around and can only find similar questions that haven't worked for me.

I have a tab-delimited .txt file with two columns that I would like to split. I need the names of the new files to be based on the first column, and the contents of each file to be the contents of the second column. For example, I would have `Name1.txt` which contains the string `word1`, another file named `Name2.txt` containing `word2` and so on. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, and would like this to be done from the command line.

```
Name1   word1
Name2   word2
Name3   word3
```

Currently I have split apart the .txt file into separate files with the following code:

```
split -1 largefile.txt
```

Now each file is of the form. With the string I want to be the name appearing first, followed by a tab and the desired contents of the file.

```
Name1   word1
```

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: I understand, I have edited the post with what I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another awk:

```
$ awk '{f=$1 ".txt";print $2 >> f;close(f)}' file
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '{
    f=$1 ".txt"     # form the filename
    print $2 >> f   # append to file in case there are non-unique $1s
    close(f)        # close file to avoid running out of fds
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  outfile=$1
  if(outfile!=prev){
    close(outfile)
  }
  print $2 > (outfile".txt")
  prev=$1
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation.

```
awk '                           ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  outfile=$1                    ##Creating variable oufile which stores first field of current line.
  if(outfile!=prev){            ##Checking condition if outfile value is NOT equal to prev variable then do following.
    close(outfile)              ##Then closing outfile(output file) in backend, this step is to avoid error of too many opened files.
  }
  print $2 > (outfile".txt")    ##Printing current line 2nd field to outfile with .txt adding to it.
  prev=$1                       ##Creating variable prev which has 1st field value of current line.
}
' Input_file                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: This split the files correctly, but left the string that became the name in the file.

Comment: @sjp, ok fixed that I am printing now only 2nd field of line. Lemme know if this works fine now?